# SQL select 2 Columns in 1 Table WHERE column1 LIKE column2

Tags: sql, ms-access

Hi guys i'm new to sql here is my table

[image]

I just want to select all values that are alike.

example output:

```
AA AA U
BB BB U
DD DD
```

Comment: Where is U coming from? Do you want the output as two columns or three columns?

Comment: You can try  select concat(symbol, ' ', comp)

Comment: I only want to output it as two columns

Comment: SELECT * FROM table WHERE comp LIKE symbol i tried this query but nothing happens.

Comment: Try the solution I posted.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Fiddle :- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c4564/7

```
    SELECT symbol,
           comp
      FROM table0
     WHERE CHARINDEX(symbol,comp) > 0
UNION ALL
     SELECT a.symbol AS symbol,
            b.comp AS comp
       FROM table0 a, table0 b
      WHERE a.symbol = b.comp 
     ;
```

Comment: can i ask why is it that there's 3 tables? i encounter an error every derived table must have its own alias?

Comment: Try now. I added alias

Comment: What sql are you using? i cant seem to get it to work

Comment: im using ms access right now it says undefined function charindex  in expression would it be possible to ask if you can convert the code to a mysql or tsql?

Comment: then u shud first revise ur tags

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 SELECT charindex.symbol, (SELECT comp FROM charindex AS C2 WHERE LEFT(c2.comp,2) = charindex.symbol) AS Comp2
    FROM charindex
    WHERE ((((SELECT comp FROM charindex AS C2 WHERE LEFT(c2.comp,2) = charindex.symbol))<>""));
```

Comment: at most one recored can be returned by this subquery

Comment: weird.  I actually ran a test and got your exact output.